# Dissolving features based on another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, area, dissolve, polygon-creation

I have two layers, see image below:

- Yellow: the ground where people can build;
- Red: existing buildings.

[image]

**Create a shapefile of all grounds where >50% of the grounds are free.**

In order to do this, I am wondering whether or not it is possible to dissolve the red features based on the yellow layer. In other words: I'd like to join/dissolve the red features within a yellow feature. If that were possible, a simple `area (red) / area (yellow) * 100` would do the trick to calculate the area in use.

Calculating `area (red) / area (yellow) * 100` without joining/dissolving red leads to an outcome that is not easily understandable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tool *Overlap analysis*:
`Processing toolbox > Vector Analysis > Overlap analysis`

This will give you the total area and percentage of each parcel covered by buildings.

[image]

[image]